# Pluralization issue in the Summary tab badge count's tooltip

Tags: bug, profile-page, badges, tooltips, plurals

There is an issue with pluralization in the badge count tooltip in the [Summary tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=summary) > "Accounts" section.

The tooltip says,

> 1 gold badge**s**

Can this be fixed?

**Screenshot for reference:**

[image: 1 gold badges]